# Elastic Search - exclude index and type from json response

Tags: json, elasticsearch

When I execute a query over an index like this:

```
{
   "_source":["bar"] , "size":100,
   "query": {
       "match_all": {}
   },
   "filter": {
       "type" : {
           "value" : "foo"
        }
    }
}
```

the response includes index, type, etc. But I already know the index and type because I specified it. This information just bloats up the size of the json data. Is there a way to exclude these from the response?

This is what I get:

```
{
"took": 31,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
    },
"hits": {
    "total": 364024,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
          {
        "_index": "foo_bar",
        "_type": "foo",
        "_id": "asdjj123123",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "bar": "blablablabla"
    }
  }
,...
```

What I want is something like this, so a response without **type,score,index**:

```
{
"took": 31,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
    },
"hits": {
    "total": 364024,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
          {
        "_id": "asdjj123123",
        "_source": {
          "bar": "blablablabla"
    }
  }
,...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, as of ES 1.6, you can use [response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/common-options.html#_response_filtering) and using the `filter_path` parameter in the query enumerate only what you need in the response:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/foo_bar/foo/_search?pretty&filter_path=hits.total,hits.max_score,hits.hits._id,hits.hits._source'
```

Comment: how can I include filter_path in a post body instead of as a get in the url?

Comment: You don't have to, you can specify a body for your query and still provide a `filter_path` in the URL.