# Elasticsearch - How to get filtered response without harming the links of each entity/field

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, mapping, querying

So assuming that i have a mapping structure like the following

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "users": {
      "properties": {
        "user": {
          "type": "nested" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I have indexed the following

**users/52**

```
 {
    "user": [
        {
            "id": 52,
            "first": "John",
            "last": "Smith",
            "age": 21,
            "school": {
                "name": "STC",
                "location": "Mt LV",
                "District": "Western"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**users/57**

```
{
    "user": [
        {
            "id": 57,
            "first": "Alice",
            "last": "White",
            "age": 25,
            "school": {
                "name": "HFC",
                "location": "DEH WLA",
                "District": "Western"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What if I want to get certain fields using the `id` and without destroying the relationship link of each other.

For an example

If `id` == 57

then the return structure should consists only `"first","age","school.name","school.District"`

```
{
    "user": [
        {
            "first": "Alice",
            "age": 25,
            "school": {
                "name": "HFC",
                "District": "Western"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How should you write a query for this sort of response in Elasticsearch?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569422/elastic-search-exclude-index-and-type-from-json-response/31570789#31570789

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering) in Elasticsearch. According to your scenario, a GET request would look like `GET /_search?user=57&filter_path=first,age,school.name,school.District`