# How to remove certain fields from json httpresponse in java?

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I am interacting with ES using Java rest client from a spring boot app and my response is JSON object.

See sample below.

What would would be the most effective way to remove certain unwanted fields ?

For example : Remove "took","successful".""_source.accountname"

Since this is a nested json object and there is high possibility of getting a larger response,I am trying to find out the most effective way.I am worried that looping through each nested object migh chew up time

```
{
  "took" : 63,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1000,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "bank",
      "_type" : "account",
      "_id" : "0",
      "sort": [0],
      "_score" : null,
      "_source" : {"account_number":0,"balance":16623,"firstname":"Bradshaw","lastname":"Mckenzie","age":29,"gender":"F","address":"244 Columbus Place","employer":"Euron","email":"bradshawmckenzie@euron.com","city":"Hobucken","state":"CO"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "bank",
      "_type" : "account",
      "_id" : "1",
      "sort": [1],
      "_score" : null,
      "_source" : {"account_number":1,"balance":39225,"firstname":"Amber","lastname":"Duke","age":32,"gender":"M","address":"880 Holmes Lane","employer":"Pyrami","email":"amberduke@pyrami.com","city":"Brogan","state":"IL"}
    }, ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: As you are saying - the response may be large and thus has unknown structure. There's no magic way in adjusting it apart from parsing and iterating through its elements

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569422/elastic-search-exclude-index-and-type-from-json-response/31570789#31570789 (hint: use `filter_path`)

Comment: This helps.Thank you.It simplifies my work!!